# Firefox MediaRecorder webm audio container

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, webm, web-mediarecorder

I am trying to record audio in a webm container using `MediaRecorder` in Firefox. The exact mime type I'm going for is `"audio/webm;codecs:vp9` which should be supported according to:

```js
MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/webm;codecs:vp9") // outputs true
```

Currently, I use the following code to record the audio:

```js
const mediaRecorderRef = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
    mimeType: "audio/webm;codecs:vp9"
});
mediaRecorderRef.start(1000);
mediaRecorderRef.ondataavailable = (e) => {
    // storing all chunks
};
```

After the recording, I create one big blob from the audio chunks as follows:

```js
new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/webm;codecs:vp9" })
```

Unfortunately, something is wrong with the created audio as I can not play it back. Recording and playing back audio does work on Chrome however.
I saw the same behavior using different codecs with the `webm` container in Firefox. Recordings did work using an `ogg` container, though this is not the format that I need.

Is it possible to record audio in a `webm` container in Firefox? If so, what is the issue with my current solution? If not, is there a different api to record audio in webm on Firefox?

Comment: Why is there a `.current.` for `ondataavailable` and not for `start()`? Besides,  `MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/webm;codecs:vp9")` outputs false on my Firefox (114.0), and passing just `audio/webm` works just fine.

Comment: Both actually had the `.current`, I removed this in my post as it wasn’t relevant here. It seems that I missed this one :)

Answer (score 0):

vp9 is a video, not an audio, codec format. [Firefox's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Audio_codecs) available audio codecs for the webm container format are opus and vorbis.

ogg is a container format like webm.

So ,it's not surprising your recorded data is garbled.

If you want both audio and video, you can specify both codecs with webm. But it looks like you need only audio.

vp9 video is more demanding to record than vp8.

Comment: I had a misunderstanding about the vp9 codec. But, unfortunately I am still not able to record audio in a webm format with for example the opus codec even though Firefox does report it as possible via the MediaRecorder `isTypeSupported` method.